# What is the different between Flyout and SettingFlyout control in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, flyout

What is the different between Flyout and SettingFlyout control in windows 8? I see that the animations are different. But is there anything else?

**UPDATE:**
This sample demonstrates how to use the ApplicationSettings API and settings flyouts to integrate an app's settings UI with the Settings charm

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49/sourcecode?fileId=50852&pathId=106473882

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SettingsFlyout is for use with the Settings Pane via the Settings contract.  The Flyout is for use in the main UX.